# Maintain vertical scroll position only using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to maintain my scroll position when clicking on a link which references `href="#"`? I know I can use Javascript to keep the current window posiiton but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it within CSS and HTML.

SOLUTION: Add `return false;` to the end of the JavaScript `click` function. This prevents the `<a href="#">` from actually trying to link to `#`, making it so the page doesn't need to reload on click, even though the rest of the function executes.

Comment: No, there is no way to do it with just HTML/CSS unless you can precalculate the entire height of the page when you generate the HTML

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this link exists solely to support a click handler, in which case said handler should be preventing the link's default effect (which is to scroll the page).

Comment: I just added a `return false` to the end of the function. Worked like a charm.